# How do I cycle through an array when I call a method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const directions = ["North", "West", "South", "East"];
```

I want `directions.next();` to cycle through them in order. How do I accomplish that in the latest iteration of the ECMAScript? I want every function that calls for directions to get what `.next()` established to be next.

Does it need to be its own mini-data structure?

Here's what I want to accomplish:

```
`["Jason Bourne", "Foma Kinaev", "John Michael Kane"]`.next() # // Jason Bourne
`["Jason Bourne", "Foma Kinaev", "John Michael Kane"]`.next() # // Foma Kinaev
`["Jason Bourne", "Foma Kinaev", "John Michael Kane"]`.next() # // John Michael Kane
`["Jason Bourne", "Foma Kinaev", "John Michael Kane"]`.next() # // Jason Bourne
```

Comment: You maybe looking for [a generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) but that might be to much for your use-case. Maybe [a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) with a `next` method might be easier to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) the values of your array continuously in a while loop (to enabled circular iteration). Then use the generator to give you an iterator that you can then call `.next()` on to grab the value:

```js
const directions = ["North", "West", "South", "East"];

function* getItr(arr) {
  while(true) yield* arr;
}

const itr = getItr(directions);
console.log(itr.next().value); // North
console.log(itr.next().value); // West
console.log(itr.next().value); // South
console.log(itr.next().value); // East
console.log(itr.next().value); // North
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript arrays don't maintain any iteration state so you'd need to handle some form of internal index pointer yourself

```js
const directions = ["North", "West", "South", "East"];

Array.prototype._current = 0
Array.prototype.next = function() {
  const cur = this[this._current]
  this._current = (this._current + 1) % this.length
  return cur
}

console.log(directions.next())
console.log(directions.next())
console.log(directions.next())
console.log(directions.next())
console.log(directions.next())
```