# How to iterate over the elements of an array in a circular manner

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

If I have an array `[1, 2, 3]`, how do I iterate over the array in a circular manner such that upon reaching the last element of the array, the next iteration will once again begin from the first element? For example, given an array `[1, 2, 3]`, the iteration should be `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...]`. In other words, I am trying to implement infinite circular iteration over the elements of an array.

This is my attempt:

```js
function makeCircularIterator(array) {
    return (function*() {
        while (true) {
            for (const element of array) {
                yield element;
            }
        }
    })();
}

// Usage example:
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
for (let n of makeCircularIterator(myArray)) {
    console.log(n);
}
```

Is the code above an idiomatic way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use a simple `for` loop, with the iteration expression involving `% length` to fall back to zero when the iteration variable reaches the limit.

Comment: You can replace the `for` loop with `yield * array` which has the same effect here.

Comment: `let i = 0; while(true) { yield array[i++ % array.length]; }`

Comment: Isn't your usage example going to cause an infinite loop? But as mentioned above by lusc, [`yield*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71245776/5648954) is a nice way

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by using an `index` to access the elements. And when the index reaches the length of the array you assign a `0` to it. This operation can be done using the `%` operator:

```
index = (index + 1) % array.length;
```

Full code:

```
function makeCircularIterator(array) {
  let index = 0;
  return (function* () {
    while (true) {
      yield array[index];
      index = (index + 1) % array.length;
    }
  })();
}
```